# values not updated after an ajax response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I am sending some form data via ajax to a php script in the same page. PHP must process the data and show results in the same page.

I am using this syntax for ajax:

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result)
    {
        updatechart();
       console.log(result);
    }
});
```

I am basically trying to update some values in a chart based on data entered in the form and after processed by a php script. I get the whole source of the page when I do `console.log(result);` and the values are updated in my console after doing this but the chart is not updated. When I view-source the page, the values remain the same. What should I do?

```
    function updatechart() {
        var json=<?php echo json_encode($GLOBALS['json']); ?>;
        var direct=json['direct'];
        var total=json['total'];
        var referred=total-direct;
        var aid=new Array();
        var count=new Array();
        for(var i=0;i<json['aid'].length;i++) {
            aid[i]=json['aid'][i];
            count[i]=json['count'][i];
        }
    var series = [{
                name : "Referred",
                data: [referred]
            }, {
                name: "Direct",
                data: [direct]
            }];
       for(var i=0; i<aid.length;i++) {
            series.push({
                name: 'AID-'+[aid[i]],
                data: [count[i]]
            })
        }
    var options = {
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'User Source Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Users']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Total users'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.percentage:.0f}%)<br/>',
            shared: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'percent'
            }
        },
            series: series
    };
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
}
```

This is my updatechart() code. The problem is, json value is not updated.

Comment: whats `updatechart()` do?

Comment: What is the body of `updatechart()`?

Comment: Your `url` parameter is empty; is that true in your code or is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: I want the url to be the same page. That is why.

Comment: Added updatechart() code. I basically want json varaible's value to be updated. Which is done in php.

Comment: JavaScript runs on the client (in this case), changing a global in PHP won't change where you output that global in javascript unless you completely reload the page or re-include the javascript again. Instead, return the json from the request and pass said json into updatechart(), as suggested by user1671639

Comment: I don't understand what am I supposed to do? I have to use $GLOBALS['json'] because json is stored as a global variable in a function in php. What is the alternative? And I am getting the full page as response. So passing it to updatechart() won't really help no?

Comment: Why must you post to the same page? if you want to do that, you'll either have to do a full page refresh every time, or completely change the output of the page depending on whether it's ajax or not. If it's ajax, you'll have to make it return ONLY the json. Changing a global var in php won't help you solve this problem, javascript can't see said global.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is expected behavior. Move your PHP processing to a different page.

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "anotherphppage.php",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result)
    {
        updatechart(result);      
    }
});
```

Try this and you'll see what I mean:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#mybutt').click(function() {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "",
                        data: 'myVar=Hello',
                        success: function(data) {
                            alert(data);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }); //END $(document).ready()

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

    Try this:<br />
    <input type="button" id="mybutt" value="Click Me">

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Pass the `result` as **parameter** to `updatechart()`

```
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "",
    data: $("form").serialize(),
    success: function(result)
    {
        updatechart(result);      
    }
});
```

then **access the results via parameter**.

```
function updatechart(result) {
//.......
//.......
console.log(result);
}
```

Hope you're trying something like this.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct way, but it looks like OP is getting the entire page in response...

Comment: @user2510555 That's probably because your PHP is still setting a global rather than returning the json. (via echo)

Comment: @user2510555 what is your ajax returning?  `result = undefined`, then what is the use of ajax call?

Comment: @user1671639 it is returning the whole page with updated values when I do `console.log(result);` inside the success function.