# Using Ajax with PHP to send image to the page

Tags: php, ajax

The user will enter some dimensions, click a button and see an image created with PHP (without a page refresh). The code I have so far is not putting the  image on the page, any idea would be greatly appreciated.

draw.html:

```
<html>

 <head>
    <title>PHP Draw Test</title>
    <script src = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src = "draw.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Test the PHP GD module</h1>

 <div>
    <label>Height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="height" min=36 max=42 step=6 required />
    <label>Width:</label>
    <input type="number" id="width" value="50"/>
    <button id="SubmitRailing" type="button">Draw!</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
 </div>

 <div id="DrawBox"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

draw.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#SubmitRailing').click(function(){

        $.post("draw.php",
            {Height: $('#Height').val(), Width: $('#Width').val()},
            function(data){
                $('#DrawBox').html(data);
            }
        );
    }); 

});
```

draw.php:

```
<?php

$height = $_POST['Height'];
$width = $_POST['Width'];
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$sand = imagecolorallocate($im, 222, 184, 135);
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);

imagefill($im, 0, 0, $white);
imagecolortransparent($im, $white);
imagefilledrectangle($im, 4, 4, 50, 25, $sand);

imagepng($im, './drawtest.png');
imagedestroy($im);

echo '<img src="drawtest.png" />';
?>
```

---

UPDATE
syntax syntax syntax
I finally got this to work, modified from @gibberish example

```
data: { Height : Height, Width : Width},
success: function(data) {alert('This was sent back: ' + data);}
```

But when I tried to substitute my original statement:

```
function(data){$('#DrawBox').html(data);}
```

it would kill the script.
Finally this worked, I didn't think it should be neccessary but there you have it:

```
success: function(data){$('#DrawBox').html(data);}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `input`s `ID`s are different from the ones retrieved in your `$.post` call: you've set your `ID`s to be both `width` and `height` and yet, you are retrieving them as `#Width` and `#Height`.

Have your jQuery code like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#SubmitRailing').on('click', function(){

        $.post("draw.php",
            {Height: $('#height').val(), Width: $('#width').val()}, // note #height and #width
            function(data){
                $('#DrawBox').html(data);
            }
        );
    }); 

});
```

**or** have your HTML like so:

```
 <div>
    <label>Height:</label>
    <input type="number" id="Height" min=36 max=42 step=6 required /> <!-- note the uppercase in the ID -->
    <label>Width:</label>
    <input type="number" id="Width" value="50"/> <!-- note the uppercase in the ID -->
    <button id="SubmitRailing" type="button">Draw!</button>
    <button type="reset">Reset</button>
 </div>
```

One of either solution will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, just some tips:

(1) Divide and conquer. Break up the problem into simple examples, and get each part working independently. For example, first just get the button to reveal a hidden div -- that shows that jQuery and the code are loaded and working properly.

```
$('#SubmitRailing').click(function(){
    $("hiddenDIV").show()
});
```

(2) Next, mod your `draw.php` page just to echo out the drawing to the screen. Ensure it is doing what you expect.

(3) Use the full `$.ajax()` format, instead of shorthand forms such as `$.post()`, `$.get()` or `$.load()`.  Not only is the structure easier to troubleshoot, but you get additional capabilities.

See these posts for simple examples of AJAX:

[A simple AJAX example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734395/form-inside-of-load-not-posting-correctly/13734466#13734466)

[More complicated example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887098/two-post-requests-one-after-the-other-second-post-request-doesnt-get-execut/17887642#17887642)

[Populate dropdown 2 based on selection in dropdown 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16924082/dynamic-drop-down-box/16924652#16924652)

---

**UPDATE:**

Further to your question, refactor your code thus:

```
<?php 
    $ht = $_POST['height']; //initially, very good idea to keep the 3 vars different, for ease of reference
    echo $ht;
?>

$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#SubmitRailing').click(function(){ 
        var Height = $('#height').val(); <-- missing ending semi-colon
        var Width = $('#width').val(); <-- missing ending semi-colon
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "draw.php", 
            data: 'height='+Height+ '&width=' +Width, // <=== changes
            success:function(data){ 
                alert('This was sent back: ' + data); 
            } 
        }); 
    }); 
});
```

***NOTE THAT:*** AJAX cannot post to the same page -- it must post to a different PHP page. [See this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529509/values-not-updated-after-an-ajax-response)

---

Also ensure that you have loaded the jQuery libraries, usually in the head tags something like this:

```
<head>
    <!-- other stuff in head -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

*If you use a CDN to load jQuery, as in the above example, it is probably already pre-loaded from other websites - especially if you load from `googleapis` or `jquery.com` CDN sites.*

---

If you want some fast, free, 10-min refresher lessons on jQuery, find free video tuts here:

https://www.thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32

or at

https://phpacademy.org/videos/jquery-basics

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I used the$.ajax() format and modified the PHP just to echo the Height - still no joy. Can you see any flaws? '<?php
$height = $_POST['Height'];
echo $height
?>'   '$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('#SubmitRailing').click(function(){
  
  var Height = $('#height').val()
  var Width = $('#width').val()
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "draw.php",
   data: Height + Width,
   success:function(data){
    alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
   }
  });
  
    }); 

});'

Comment: This comment syntax is a bitch  :(
@D4V1D   
draw.php:   
`<?php
$height = $_POST['Height'];
echo $height
?>`
   
draw.js   
`$(document).ready(function() {
 
    $('#SubmitRailing').click(function(){
  
  var Height = $('#height').val()
  var Width = $('#width').val()
  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "draw.php",
   data: Height + Width,
   success:function(data){
    alert('This was sent back: ' + data);
   }
  });
  
    }); 

});`

Comment: @BartBremmers See response added to my answer.  In future, to add formatted code as above, just use the **edit** link under the original question and just add an UPDATE to the bottom of the question with any new code. *To separate the new UPDATE info from body of main answer, just make an isolated line that has nothing but three dashes at beginning (creates horizontal line).*

Comment: Thanks gibberish. I incorporated your corrections with no joy. I got so frustrated I straight copied your code to draw.php & draw.js and still no joy. When I click the button nothing happens. I know the php works, I use `$height = 300;` & `width = 300;` and point the browser directly to draw.php it works. So something is not working with the js but I am baffled. Could it be the `<script src = ...` is that pointing to the correct resource?

Comment: @BartBremmers This may be it -- see new addition at bottom of answer.

Comment: I put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` in the head, your code  `success:function(data){alert('This was sent back: ' + data);}` works, I get message **This was sent back <img src="drawtest.png">**, when I replace your success:function with my code `function(data){$('#DrawBox').html(data);}` it dies quietly. We're close to something  :-)